# How add accounts to web3.js

Tags: web3js

I'm using web3.jp 1.0

How to connect (log in) my existing account (for example, created through myetherwallet) to make a transaction or call contract?

As I understand it, the list of accounts is provided by the RPC node, because when using testerpc in the Web3.eth.accounts, test accounts were available, but new ones were not added.

```
const Web3 = require('web3');
console.log(web3.eth.getAccounts()) // []
```

thank you!

Answer (score 3):

To create new accounts on Ethereum you can use following instructions:

```
var Accounts = require('web3-eth-accounts');
var accounts = new Accounts('http://localhost:8545');
//Generates an account with public key and private key
web3.eth.accounts.create();
> {
    address: "0xb8CE9ab6943e0eCED004cDe8e3bBed6568B2Fa01",
    privateKey: "0x348ce564d427a3311b6536bbcff9390d69395b06ed6c486954e971d960fe8709",
    signTransaction: function(tx){...},
    sign: function(data){...},
    encrypt: function(password){...}
  }
```

Comment: User asked for adding existing account

Answer (score 3):

Here's how you add an existing account, if you have the account's private key and password:

```js
const account = web3.eth.accounts.privateKeyToAccount("0x" + YOUR_PRIVATE_KEY);
await web3.eth.personal.unlockAccount(account.address, YOUR_PASSWORD);
```

Answer (score 2):

Creating accounts on ethereum -

1. Make sure you have installed the web3 node module.
2. If not then you can install it using `npm install web3`

Example-

```
var Web3 = require('web3')
var web3 = new Web3(Web3.givenProvider || 'http://localhost:7545')

//Now to create an account

web3.eth.accounts.create()

> {
    address: "0xF2CD2AA0c7926743B1D4310b2BC984a0a453c3d4",
    privateKey:"0xd7325de5c2c1cf0009fac77d3d04a9c004b038883446b065871bc3e831dcd098",
    signTransaction: function(tx){...},
    sign: function(data){...},
    encrypt: function(password){...}
}
```

For more information, refer to the web3.js documentation - 
https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3.html

Comment: User asked for adding existing account